くれる used to modifiy nouns?

チョコくれるような子いるの?

A mother asks her son on Valentine's Day. What I don't get, is how くれる is being used here?
Is it about how there is a girl that will give the chocolate and and the kid will receive?
Or is it more "is a girl that receive chocolate"?

[呉]{く}れる (showing the kanji although it isn't normally used) isn't only an auxiliary, but also a standalone verb "to give". Here, を is omitted; the chocolate is what is given.
The mother asks (の) if there exists (いる) a girl (well, child - 子 - and here either は or が is also omitted) of the sort (ような) "someone gives chocolate to someone" (チョコをくれる).
Grammatically, this wouldn't appear to tell us whether the girl is the giver or the recipient, since either would be valid for this kind of descriptive phrase. However, culture tells us: in Japan, women give chocolate to men on Valentine's Day, and men return the favour a month later on White Day.

In terms of basic semantics and social structuring, one generally doesn't say くれる about one's own actions in giving someone something, no? Thus, we can tell from the use of くれる that the 子 must be giving to the askee.

@EiríkrÚtlendi Ah, yes, there's also the usual くれる・あげる distinction. But since this proposition is being asked about by a third party, it's a bit harder to reason about that way.
